# How to display the video captured from iPhone's camera on the screen without saving it?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation

I am new to iOS and multimedia development and I am trying to capture a video from iPhone's camera and show it on the screen without saving it in the memory.

I have written the following code so far with the help of sample codes that I got online:

**Header file:**

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@class AVCamCaptureManager, AVCamPreviewView, AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *previewView;

- (IBAction)StartCapture:(id)sender;
- (void)setCaptureSession;
@end
```

**Implementation file**

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *captureOutput;
@property (nonatomic, weak) AVCaptureDeviceInput *activeVideoInput;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;

@end

@implementation ViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)StartCapture:(id)sender
{
if ([sender isSelected])
{
    [sender setSelected:NO];
    [self.captureOutput stopRecording];

}
else
{
[sender setSelected:YES];

if (!self.captureOutput)
    {
    self.captureOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    [self.captureSession addOutput:self.captureOutput];
}
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}
}

- (void)setCaptureSession
{
self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
NSError *error;

// Set up hardware devices
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (videoDevice)
{
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
    if (input)
    {
        [self.captureSession addInput:input];
        self.activeVideoInput = input;
    }
}
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
if (audioDevice) {
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];
    if (audioInput) {
        [self.captureSession addInput:audioInput];
    }
}

// Start running session so preview is available
[self.captureSession startRunning];

// Set up preview layer
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds;
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    //[[self.previewLayer connection] setVideoOrientation:[self currentVideoOrientation]];
    [self.previewView.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
});
}

// Re-enable capture session if not running currently 
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
if (![self.captureSession isRunning])
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self.captureSession startRunning];
    });
}
}

// Stop running capture session when this view disappears
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
if ([self.captureSession isRunning])
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self.captureSession stopRunning];
    });
}
}
@end
```

Please tell me what should I write in the IBAction method (which gets called when capture video button is pressed) and how to use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to make the video being captured to be displayed on the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I was missing. It was really stupid for me to do this. I didn't call the function `setCapture` at all. Hence nothing was getting visible on the screen.

I just called `setCapture` in viewDidLoad function and problem solved.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setCaptureSession];
}
```

Still there is an issue with the video when phone's orientation is changed which I will have to work upon but now whatever is being captured by the camera is visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You want an AVCapturePreviewLayer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW22

As far as what to write in your IBAction method, that'll depend on how you want your app to behave. If you want it to load with the capture session and preview running, you don't really need a button. If you're starting your capture session via the button, just put the PreviewLayer code in the same method (after you have inited your capture session).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the AVCapturePreviewLayer in the code that I have posted above and I have also done all that was there int the code in the link that you suggested, but still I can't see the video on the screen. Please check the method "setCaptureSession" in my code once and tell me what I am missing.

Comment: I see you found the problem. I loaded your code into a test project and nothing happened. Same as you. Then I noticed the setCaptureSession call was missing in viewDidLoad. I always forget to start things too.